# Why am I getting the error: ValueError: The truth value of a Series is ambiguous. Use a.empty, a.bool(), a.item(), a.any() or a.all()

Tags: python, sqlite, csv, dataframe, for-loop

Fielding is a DataFrame, but I am not sure why I am getting this error:

> ValueError: The truth value of a Series is ambiguous. Use a.empty, a.bool(), a.item(), a.any() or a.all()

```
RAR = []
for i in range(0,len(Fielding)):
    position = (Fielding['POS'][i])
    value = 0 
    if position == 'C':
        value = (9.0/150.0) * (Fielding['GS'][i])
    elif position == 'SS':
        value = (7.0/150.0) * (Fielding['GS'][i])
    elif position == '2B':
        value = (3.0/150.0) * (Fielding['GS'][i])
    elif position == '3B':
        value = (2.0/150.0) * (Fielding['GS'][i])
    elif position == '1B':
        value = (-9.5/150.0) * (Fielding['GS'][i])
    else:
        value = 0
    RAR.append(value)
```

Here is a sample of my DataFrame.

```
               yearID teamID   playerID POS    G     GS
yearID teamID                                          
1994   FLO       1994    FLO  abbotku01  SS   99   93.0
       OAK       1994    OAK  aldremi01  1B   27   20.0
       OAK       1994    OAK  aldremi01  OF   35   18.0
       SLN       1994    SLN  alicelu01  2B   53   48.0
       SLN       1994    SLN  alicelu01  OF    2    0.0
       TOR       1994    TOR  alomaro01  2B  106  102.0
       CLE       1994    CLE  alomasa02   C   78   78.0
       MON       1994    MON   aloumo01  OF  106  106.0
       SEA       1994    SEA  amarari01  1B    2    0.0
       SEA       1994    SEA  amarari01  2B   42   37.0
       SEA       1994    SEA  amarari01  OF   16    7.0
       SEA       1994    SEA  amarari01  SS    7    5.0
       CLE       1994    CLE  amaroru02  OF   12    0.0
       BAL       1994    BAL  anderbr01  OF  109  109.0
       CAL       1994    CAL  anderga01  OF    4    3.0
       SEA       1994    SEA  anthoer01  OF   71   65.0
       FLO       1994    FLO  ariasal01  3B   15    4.0
       FLO       1994    FLO  ariasal01  SS   20   18.0
       LAN       1994    LAN  ashlebi01  OF    2    2.0
       SDN       1994    SDN  ausmubr01  1B    1    0.0
       SDN       1994    SDN  ausmubr01   C   99   94.0
```

Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: Please let me know if you need anymore information!

Comment: A sample of what the dataframe `Fielding` contains would be helpful.

Comment: @JayMody Apologies, I updated the question accordingly.

Comment: Hello, why are you putting Fielding['GS'][i] inside ()? I think this might be the problem since your field is casted to a tuple

Comment: Hi @FransDel unfortunately, removing the parenthesis did not solve the problem

Comment: @Neel could you print out type(Fielding['POS'][i])

Comment: @FransDel when I do print(type(Fielding['POS'][i])), I get <class 'str'>

Comment: @Neel At which line are you getting this error?

Comment: @FransDel are you not allowed to do if statements with dataFrames?

Comment: @Neel you aren't allowed to directly make bool logic (if statements or asserts) with Series or DataFrames directly

Comment: @FransDel do you know how I can fix this

Comment: @Neel I'm trying to see could you print out print(type(Fielding['GS'][i]))

Comment: @FransDel I get <class 'str'>. This same result occurs the number of times it iterates through the loop.

Comment: @Neel You need to give us a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example). The csv data you provide isn't structured right. When I paste it into a text file, and load the csv into a var called `Fielding` I should be able to exactly reproduce your error. Please make sure you are providing the correct information and data so I can reproduce the error, and work from there.